# I have a issue with collision equation

Tags: c++, 2d, simulation, equation

```cpp
int Electra2D::Collision()
{
    for (std::list<Entity>::iterator affecting = entities.begin(); affecting != entities.end(); ++affecting) {
        for (std::list<Entity>::iterator affected = entities.begin(); affected != entities.end(); ++affected) {
            if (affecting->type == DrawTypes::Circle && affected->type == DrawTypes::Circle && affecting->object->id != affected->object->id) {
                float distance = affected->pos.getDistance(affecting->pos);
                float limit = ((ObjectCircle*)affected->object)->radius + ((ObjectCircle*)affecting->object)->radius;
                if (distance <= limit) {
                    Vector2 SP = affected->velocity * affected->mass + affecting->velocity * affecting->mass;
                    Vector2 V2 = (SP - (affected->velocity-affecting->velocity) * affecting->mass) / (affected->mass + affecting->mass);
                    affecting->velocity = V2 + (affected->velocity-affecting->velocity);
                    affected->velocity = V2;
                    //Equation https://imgur.com/cQqBn9S
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote base for 2d simulation in c ++ with d2d1 but when I wrote an equation for collision algorithm I made mistake but I don't know where I mistaken so i need help guys :)
affecting pointer is V1,m1 and affected pointer is V2,m2.
V2' is in code V2, and Sum of momentum in code SP
[image: My beautiful equation]
[Source](https://github.com/Septillioner/SciElectra/blob/c83cd4117f16a7336505d52a25b2e73c010d685b/SciElectra/Source/Private/Electra2D.cpp#L93)

Edit:
I found my mistake, still thanks. My mistake is I created one dimension equation for two-dimension simulation. When I create an equation I will share my equation and code in this post.

Comment: Are you using C++11 or newer? If so, you can rewrite things like `std::list<Entity>::iterator affecting = entities.begin()` using `auto`, like this: `auto affecting = entities.begin()` - much easier. In fact, the whole loop could be made into a range-based for loop: `for(auto& affecting : entities) { ... }` which makes `affecting` a reference to the element in the container, not an iterator.

Comment: Thanks, I will use it after this moment